# Error 'document' is null or not object found when passing value back from child window to parent window

Tags: jquery

I have tried to use the following code to passing value back from the child window back to the parent window

```
      <tr>
        <th class="clLabel">Unit</th>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" /> 
        </td>
      </tr>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#test").click(function () {
        var parent = $(parent.document.body);
        $(parent).find('input#sUnit').val("test");
        window.close();
    });

</script>
```

But some how error message always display when it's come to this code of line

## NOTE: parent page and the child page is holding in the difference host (will this cause the problem?)

[image]

Does anyone know what is it going on? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this will work.

```
<script>
$(function (){
     $("#test").click(function () {
        var parent = window.opener.document;
        $(parent).find('input#sUnit').val("test");
        window.close();
    });
})
</script>
<a href="#" id="test">test</a>
```

**UPDATE**

the opender Script

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('search.php', '_blank', 'height=200, width=300');" value="launch!" />
<input id="sUnit" value="" type="text"/>
```

Comment: @experimentX: the error message is gone. but somehow it's doesn't seem assign the value "test" into sUnit :(

Comment: @JinYong make sure that you have a `input` element that can hold `value`  and with an id `sUnit` in the parent window. In my case, it does.

Comment: @experimentX:I do the coding in .net will it work for my jquery code? see my update above  (<asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" /> )

Comment: @JinYoung not sure, ... if it supports javascript then sure it must work.

Comment: @JinYong try running from browser, it's just pure js, if it works on your browser, then sure, it will work anywhere .. on production version.